# The "Hello World" example appears with no MenuBar and no Menu Items

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, ubuntu-23.10

I copied the "Hello World" example (`wxWidgets/samples/minimum`) `minimum.cpp` and its `CMakeLists.txt` info an empty folder MyPrj.
I compiled and built but the resulting screen has no MenuBar and no MenuItems anymore

```
raphy@raohy:~/MyPrj$ cmake -B builddir
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found wxWidgets: -L/usr/local/lib;-pthread;;;-lwx_gtk3u_core-3.3;-lwx_baseu-3.3 (found suitable version "3.3.0", minimum required is "3.3") 
-- Configuring done (0.3s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/raphy/MyPrj/builddir
raphy@raohy:~/MyPrj$ 
raphy@raohy:~/MyPrj$ cmake --build builddir
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MyPrj.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable MyPrj
[100%] Built target MyPrj
raphy@raohy:~/MyPrj$ 
raphy@raohy:~/MyPrj$ ./builddir/MyPrj
```

[image]

This is the `CMakeLists.txt` file :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)

if(APPLE AND NOT CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET)
    # If no deployment target has been set default to the minimum supported
    # OS version (this has to be set before the first project() call)
    if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "iOS")
        set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 12.0 CACHE STRING "iOS Deployment Target")
    else()
        set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.10 CACHE STRING "macOS Deployment Target")
    endif()
endif()

# Name the project
project(MyPrj)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# Request the required wxWidgets libs
find_package(wxWidgets 3.3 COMPONENTS REQUIRED core base)

# Include the wxWidgets use file to initialize various settings
if(wxWidgets_USE_FILE)
    include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
endif()

# Define a variable containing a list of source files for the project
set(SRC_FILES
    src/main.cpp
    )

if(WIN32)
    # Include a RC file for windows
    list(APPEND SRC_FILES ../sample.rc)
elseif(APPLE)
    # Add an icon for the apple .app file
    list(APPEND SRC_FILES ./src/icons/wxmac.icns)
endif()

# Define the build target for the executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 MACOSX_BUNDLE ${SRC_FILES})
# Link required libraries to the executable
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})

if(APPLE)
    set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
        RESOURCE "./src/icons/wxmac.icns"
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_ICON_FILE wxmac.icns
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_COPYRIGHT "Copyright wxWidgets"
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER "org.wxwidgets.minimal"
        )
endif()
```

and this is the `./src/main.cpp` file :

```
raphy@raohy:~/MyPrj$ cat ./src/main.cpp 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Name:        minimal.cpp
// Purpose:     Minimal wxWidgets sample
// Author:      Julian Smart
// Modified by:
// Created:     04/01/98
// Copyright:   (c) Julian Smart
// Licence:     wxWindows licence
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// ============================================================================
// declarations
// ============================================================================

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// headers
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// For compilers that support precompilation, includes "wx/wx.h".
#include "wx/wxprec.h"


// for all others, include the necessary headers (this file is usually all you
// need because it includes almost all "standard" wxWidgets headers)
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include "wx/wx.h"
#endif

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// resources
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// the application icon (under Windows it is in resources and even
// though we could still include the XPM here it would be unused)
#ifndef wxHAS_IMAGES_IN_RESOURCES
    #include "./icons/sample.xpm"
#endif

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// private classes
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Define a new application type, each program should derive a class from wxApp
class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    // override base class virtuals
    // ----------------------------

    // this one is called on application startup and is a good place for the app
    // initialization (doing it here and not in the ctor allows to have an error
    // return: if OnInit() returns false, the application terminates)
    virtual bool OnInit() override;
};

// Define a new frame type: this is going to be our main frame
class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    // ctor(s)
    MyFrame(const wxString& title);

    // event handlers (these functions should _not_ be virtual)
    void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);

private:
    // any class wishing to process wxWidgets events must use this macro
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// constants
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// IDs for the controls and the menu commands
enum
{
    // menu items
    Minimal_Quit = wxID_EXIT,

    // it is important for the id corresponding to the "About" command to have
    // this standard value as otherwise it won't be handled properly under Mac
    // (where it is special and put into the "Apple" menu)
    Minimal_About = wxID_ABOUT
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// event tables and other macros for wxWidgets
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// the event tables connect the wxWidgets events with the functions (event
// handlers) which process them. It can be also done at run-time, but for the
// simple menu events like this the static method is much simpler.
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_MENU(Minimal_Quit,  MyFrame::OnQuit)
    EVT_MENU(Minimal_About, MyFrame::OnAbout)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

// Create a new application object: this macro will allow wxWidgets to create
// the application object during program execution (it's better than using a
// static object for many reasons) and also implements the accessor function
// wxGetApp() which will return the reference of the right type (i.e. MyApp and
// not wxApp)
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);

// ============================================================================
// implementation
// ============================================================================

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// the application class
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// 'Main program' equivalent: the program execution "starts" here
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    // call the base class initialization method, currently it only parses a
    // few common command-line options but it could be do more in the future
    if ( !wxApp::OnInit() )
        return false;

    // create the main application window
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame("Minimal wxWidgets App");

    // and show it (the frames, unlike simple controls, are not shown when
    // created initially)
    frame->Show(true);

    // success: wxApp::OnRun() will be called which will enter the main message
    // loop and the application will run. If we returned false here, the
    // application would exit immediately.
    return true;
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// main frame
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// frame constructor
MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title)
       : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title)
{
    // set the frame icon
    SetIcon(wxICON(sample));

#if wxUSE_MENUBAR
    // create a menu bar
    wxMenu *fileMenu = new wxMenu;

    // the "About" item should be in the help menu
    wxMenu *helpMenu = new wxMenu;
    helpMenu->Append(Minimal_About, "&About\tF1", "Show about dialog");

    fileMenu->Append(Minimal_Quit, "E&xit\tAlt-X", "Quit this program");

    // now append the freshly created menu to the menu bar...
    wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar();
    menuBar->Append(fileMenu, "&File");
    menuBar->Append(helpMenu, "&Help");

    // ... and attach this menu bar to the frame
    SetMenuBar(menuBar);
#else // !wxUSE_MENUBAR
    // If menus are not available add a button to access the about box
    wxSizer* sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    wxButton* aboutBtn = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, "About...");
    aboutBtn->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MyFrame::OnAbout, this);
    sizer->Add(aboutBtn, wxSizerFlags().Center());
    SetSizer(sizer);
#endif // wxUSE_MENUBAR/!wxUSE_MENUBAR

#if wxUSE_STATUSBAR
    // create a status bar just for fun (by default with 1 pane only)
    CreateStatusBar(2);
    SetStatusText("Welcome to wxWidgets!");
#endif // wxUSE_STATUSBAR
}


// event handlers

void MyFrame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    // true is to force the frame to close
    Close(true);
}

void MyFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    wxMessageBox(wxString::Format
                 (
                    "Welcome to %s!\n"
                    "\n"
                    "This is the minimal wxWidgets sample\n"
                    "running under %s.",
                    wxVERSION_STRING,
                    wxGetOsDescription()
                 ),
                 "About wxWidgets minimal sample",
                 wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION,
                 this);
}
raphy@raohy:~/MyPrj$
```

What is strange is that compiling and building within the original `wxWidgets/samples/minimal` folder produces an output with menubar and menu items.

[image]

If I copy `CMakeLists.txt` and `minimum.cpp` file into a brand new folder, compiling and building produces an executable which does not show any menubar and any menu items

I discovered now that when rebooting Ubuntu 23.10, the MenuBar and Menu Items do not show up also when compiling and building in the original `wxWidgets/samples/minimum` folder:

[image]

I guess, than, it has to be related to something missing/misbehaving/not correctly loading within the Ubuntu 23.10 system

Update 1)

I've put in `bashrc` file

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/wx
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/wx/3.3.0
```

to set and fix the LD_LIBRARY_OATH for wxWidgets but still it doesn't "see" the wxWidgets library.

If I do:

```
raphy@raohy:~$ sudo ldconfig /etc/ld.so.conf.d/wx.conf
```

where:

```
raphy@raohy:~$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/wx.conf 
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/wx
/usr/local/lib/wx/3.3.0
```

then. executing the built wxWidget "Hello World" example in another screen, but ONLY IF in another screen, gives the correct MenuBar and Menu Items

How to make it work without needing to do `sudo ldconfig /etc/ld.so.conf.d/wx.conf` or without needing to do `source ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: I recognize the title. Did you post (and delete) the exact same question before? Please don't do that. Edit your original question if it needs to be improved. Reposting the same question over and over will be found out, and downvoted/closed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 
I beg your pardon, "sir". I deleted the previous post, because yesterday night copying CMakeLists.txt and minimum.cpp file "solved" the issue. But today the problem persists also doing so. Would be so kind in giving an help?

Comment: @Raphael10, what changed? Did it pick up and install any updates automatically?

Comment: @Igor I don't think it's an issue of automatic updates: ``` raphy@raohy:~$ cat  /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades 
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";``` .  I discovered that doing `sudo ldconfig /etc/ld.so.conf.d/wx.conf` let the execution in another screen to be correct. I described what I discovered in Update 1 in the post

Comment: @Raphael10, where should I respond - here or on the forum? This is why cross-posting at the same time is frown upon...

Comment: @Igor Where do you prefer to respond? If you respond in the forum, and I delete this question above. If you respond here, I delete (but how?) the question in the forum